# The yellow background messages on the tools page

Tags: support, flags

Nothing stays [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged) for very long, so I hope I won't get yelled at too much for the lack of a link.

Sometimes there is a message with a yellow background like, 'off topic; belongs on Super User', but when I click on close, there are no existing close votes of that form. Is this message a guess based on looking at keywords in the text?

Comment: that user doesn't have 3k rep so they can't cast a close vote of that type. But they can flag..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The yellow message comes from the flag option that a user selects not from a close vote.

**Flag process Step 1**

[image: Flag Process Step 1]

**Flag Process Step 2**

[image: Flag Process Step 2]

**Flag Process Step 3**

[image: Flag Process Step 3]

Gives you the following flag message:

[image: Flag Result]

Comment: What 'flag option' corresponds to 'off-topic, superuser'?

Comment: @Rosinante: I have added the steps that would be followed by a user who is flagging a question. Remember a flag is not the same as a close vote.

Comment: it never occurred to me that the flag system now had a complete parallel to the close reasons :-)